# Web Scraping Jquery tables with BeautifulSoup and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the data from a table in a site that everyday is updated from this site
http://mananciais.sabesp.com.br/HistoricoSistemas?SistemaId=0.

I'm learning BeautifulSoup and Selenium and trying to access the data with these packages.

However, the source code of the website does not reveal the data in the table. As I understand it the site was built using jQuery Grid.

Until now I did only this, despite having tried several things.

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver

# Escolhe o driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Acessa o site
site = 'http://mananciais.sabesp.com.br/HistoricoSistemas'
driver.get(site)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

How can access this data?
I want to make analysis with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is rendered by Java Scripts.You need to wait for page to be load properly before get the page_source.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`()

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# Escolhe o driver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# Acessa o site
site = 'http://mananciais.sabesp.com.br/HistoricoSistemas'
driver.get(site)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"contenttabledivjqxGrid")))
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome!
Improving!
It's works, but return only a visible part of the table...
... the part that the user have to roll down and right the BeautifulSoup doesn't get.

Thanks @KunduK! I'll continuous study!